# How do I tell if my ActiveMQ message was delivered to the final destination?

Tags: c++, activemq-classic

Here's my situation:

1. My Master application sends a message to a Slave application via ActiveMQ.
2. When the Slave receives the message, it sends an acknowledgement back to the Master.

However, for cases where the Slave is not running, I want the Master to be alerted that the message could not be delivered.

For OpenAMQ, there is a "mandatory" flag, which causes the broker to return the message to the sender if it was unable to immediately deliver it to the destination.

Is there something similar in ActiveMQ that will allow the Master to determine that the Slave is not available?

Answer (score 1):

The final destination? What is the deployment topology? Do you have one ActiveMQ broker, or two clustered brokers on each of the master/slave applications?

I think the easiest way in either case is to issue a request/reply ping from master to slave. If the response does not show up within XX sec, consider the slave node offline.